# Docker build taking too long when installing grpcio via pip

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, grpc

I have a Dockerfile which installs a few packages via pip.
Some of them are requiring `grpcio`, and it takes a few minutes only to build this part.

Does anyone have a tip to speed up this part?

```
Installing collected packages: python-dateutil, azure-common, azure-nspkg, azure-storage, jmespath, docutils, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, smmap2, gitdb2, GitPython, grpcio, protobuf, googleapis-common-protos, grpc-google-iam-v1, pytz, google-api-core, google-cloud-pubsub
Found existing installation: python-dateutil 2.7.3
  Uninstalling python-dateutil-2.7.3:
    Successfully uninstalled python-dateutil-2.7.3
Running setup.py install for grpcio: started
Running setup.py install for grpcio: still running...
Running setup.py install for grpcio: still running...
Running setup.py install for grpcio: still running...
```

Thanks.

Comment: What docker image are you using, `alpine`? Also, what is the target Python version in the image?

Comment: please use the cache and you dont need to build thoese layers everytime , put new things in the end of dockerfile

Comment: Having the same problem building the wheel for grpcio, see code here: https://github.com/ohduran/Promenade/blob/master/instarest/compose/local/django/Dockerfile

Comment: @ohduran your link is dead

Comment: You're right @Hyperbole, new link: https://github.com/ohduran/Promenade/blob/master/compose/local/django/Dockerfile

Comment: If you are using alpine, it takes time to compile from scratch https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22815#issuecomment-649690837

Answer (score 40):

I had the same issue and it was solved by upgrading pip:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Here's a word from one of the maintainers of grpc project:

- [pip grpcio install is (still) very slow #22815](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22815)

Comment: you made my day!

Comment: Thanks bro. Indeed, upgrading pip is essential for getting rid of this issue. Have no idea of what might be going wrong with grpcio and Docker.

Comment: still no aarch64 (armv8) wheels for grpcio, so this doesn't work on most newer arm processers

Comment: why isn't this marked as the answer??

Comment: You mean upgrade pip on the host or in the Dockerfile like `RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: That depends, Oleg. If your `python3-pip` installed on the container is outdated, you might consider RUNning a command for upgrading pip. I'd say that, having the latest version of `pip` would do the trick. Worth testing.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue, fixed it by using a virtualenv and a multistage dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.7-slim as base

# ---- compile image -----------------------------------------------
FROM base AS compile-image
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential \
  gcc

RUN python -m venv /app/env
ENV PATH="/app/env/bin:$PATH"

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# pip install is fast here (while slow without the venv) :
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# ---- build image -----------------------------------------------
FROM base AS build-image
COPY --from=compile-image /app/env /app/env

# Make sure we use the virtualenv:
ENV PATH="/app/env/bin:$PATH"
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
```

Here is my requirements.txt :

```
fastapi==0.27.*
grpcio-tools==1.21.*
uvicorn==0.7.*
```

Comment: I am curious why virtualenv would make a difference here.

Answer (score 1):

Some docker images (looking at you, Alpine) can't pull prebuilt wheels. Use a docker image that can, like Debian.

Check out this [nice write-up on why](https://github.com/tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask-docker#-alpine-python-warning). I'll reproduce a quote from it, that's especially apt:

> But for Python, as Alpine doesn't use the standard tooling used for
> building Python extensions, when installing packages, in many cases
> Python (pip) won't find a precompiled installable package (a "wheel")
> for Alpine. And after debugging lots of strange errors you will
> realize that you have to install a lot of extra tooling and build a
> lot of dependencies just to use some of these common Python packages.
>
> -- [Sebastián Ramírez](https://github.com/tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask-docker#-alpine-python-warning)